# MongoDb $avg from multiple object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i got the data form this code:

```
db.getCollection('lampus').aggregate([
  {
      $unwind: '$data'
  },
{
$match: {_id: "sensor-2",
  'data.tanggal': {
    $gt: (new Date(new ISODate()-1*1000*60*60*24))
  }
}
}, 
{
$sort: {
  'data.tanggal': 1
}
},

])
```

and the result is:

```
[{"_id":"sensor-2","data":{"sensor": 
{"intensitas":3,"arus":0.05},"tanggal":"2018-08-05T14:05:58.757Z"}},
{"_id":"sensor-2","data":{"sensor": 
{"intensitas":11,"arus":0.05},"tanggal":"2018-08-05T14:05:58.756Z"}},
{"_id":"sensor-2","data":{"sensor": 
{"intensitas":8,"arus":0.05},"tanggal":"2018-08-05T14:05:52.654Z"}},
{"_id":"sensor-2","data":{"sensor": 
{"intensitas":13,"arus":0.05},"tanggal":"2018-08-05T14:05:51.152Z"}},
{"_id":"sensor-2","data":{"sensor": 
{"intensitas":15,"arus":0.05},"tanggal":"2018-08-05T14:05:46.651Z"}},
{"_id":"sensor-2","data":{"sensor": 
{"intensitas":13,"arus":0.1},"tanggal":"2018-08-04T14:05:45.150Z"}}]
```

there is so many "_id: sensor-2" that becaus $unwind operation from code above.
Quest is:
 1. there is an "intensitas" value, how can i $avg all "intensitas" from all object?
 2. how i implement the query to the NodeJs, because that is "ISODate" format from  mongodb, because when i try "ISODate is undefined" in nodeJs.

Comment: At the end of this aggregate do a `$group` with `$avg` on `intensitas`. For the ISODate - it comes form the mongoDB client.

Answer (score 0):

1-you could use $avg that available in $group with null id in $group.
($avg is available in $project too)

Answer (score 0):

finally i can do what i want, i use this code:

```
db.getCollection('lampus').aggregate([
{
  $unwind: '$data'
},
{
$match: {_id: "sensor-2",
  'data.tanggal': {
    $gt: (new Date(new ISODate()-1*1000*60*60*24))
  }
}
},

{
$sort: {
  'data.tanggal': 1
}
},
{
   $group:
     {
       _id: "$_id",
       RataInten: { $avg: { $multiply: [ "$data.sensor.intensitas" ] } },
       RataArus: { $avg: { $multiply: [ "$data.sensor.arus" ] } },
     }
 },
 {$project: {data:[{arus :"$RataArus",intensitas :"$RataInten"}]}},
 { $out : "3hari" }, 

 ])
```

on the { $out : "3hari" }, that is create new of collection tha called "3hari" and i get this :

```
{
"_id" : "sensor-2",
"data" : [ 
    {
        "arus" : 0.1,
        "intensitas" : 5.0,
        "today" : ISODate("2018-08-05T15:08:17.513+07:00")
    }
]
}
```

that is what i want, but i got the problem, i need more "data" array, like i expect:

```
{
"_id" : "sensor-2",
"data" : [ 
    {
        "arus" : 0.1,
        "intensitas" : 5.0,
        "today" : ISODate("2018-08-05T15:08:17.513+07:00")
    },
    {
        "arus" : 0.1,
        "intensitas" : 8.0,
        "today" : ISODate("2018-08-08T15:08:17.513+07:00")
    },
    {
        "arus" : 0.1,
        "intensitas" : 9.0,
        "today" : ISODate("2018-08-12T15:08:17.513+07:00")
    }
]
}
```

yess i need the array of data updated, and has more array ...